# How to Debug Android Media Box

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, media

how to connect Android Media box device  for debugging with android studio.
Which wires should be connected with CPU to android media box.

This is my android media box and i want to debug an app that is installed in this device with android studio

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Jesurun-A19-Android-4-2-Dual-Core-4GB-TV-Box-Media-Player-Bluetooth-HDMI-EU-Plug-/351173432356?nma=true&si=BB2I66819OnY3IYEliRtg7JcHoM%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the listing and the Type-B USB slot on the back can probably connect to your computer.

However, you still need a few things to able to debug anything:

1. Some way to go to the device's Settings screen to enable installs from Unknown Sources (by default it will only allow apps from the Play Store or whatever store its manufacturer set it to) - not sure if Media Box has that option, even if every phone/tablet I've seen does include it
2. Some way to enable Developer options (typically tap your OS version in settings 7 times, I believe, but could be some other setting)
3. The application needs to be debuggable. Everything installed on that device will be a production copy with the "debuggable" flag set to false. Apps you create and push over USB will typically have this flag set to true and therefore allow you to see logs, etc

Comment: I just want to know how will I connect android media device to cpu the way we connect another android device (mobile/tablet) to cpu by usb wire.

Comment: You will need a USB Type B to USB Type A cable. The kind you typically see on printers and older USB peripherals...

Here's an image of one: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/4109I2PdxCL._SY355_.jpg

Comment: Hi,Thanks But USB type B to USB type A cable will not attached to computer for debugging. I don't have port for USB B in media box. I have bought USB type A to USB Type A wire. It attached first time and shows USBis installing But I again attached to my computer nothing is showing.

Comment: So if there's a physical connection, ADB should detect the device. Have you installed ADB or Android Studio? You can use the ADB shell commands to detect devices: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html

Comment: First time,It detects the device but now m attaching the device it is not showing.

Comment: how will i attach my device.

Comment: Based on the product photos for the listing, I was thinking of the USB port in the back, between the HDMI and the LAN port. The 4 USB Type A slots on the side, I'm not sure will connect as a device. I think the device is meant to act as a host for those 4 slots.

Comment: Okay Thanks shobhik